# why can't i pass a reference to my unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I have a vector of `std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t>` and I want to pass a reference of the `unique_ptr` within this vector to another function:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t>> _kitchens;

for (int i = 0; i < (int)_kitchens.size(); i++)
{
    if (FD_ISSET(_kitchens[i]->socket, &this->_readfds))
    {
        handleKitchenRet(std::cref<std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t>>(_kitchens[i]));
    }
}

void Reception::handleKitchenRet(std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t> kitch)
{
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work. How could I do that?

The error message:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = kitchen_control_s; _Dp = std::default_delete<kitchen_control_s>]' 
  169 |             handleKitchenRet(std::ref<uKCtrl>(_kitchens[i]));
```

Comment: `Reception::handleKitchenRet(std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t> kitch)` - where's the reference?  And related, where's the *error message* that is causing you grief, yet for whatever reason you chose *not* to include in your post?

Comment: You are trying to make *a copy* of `std::unique_ptr`, and, as the name "unique" suggests, it's not possible. What are you trying to do? Should `handleKitchenRet` take unique_ptr argument by reference instead of by value?

Comment: You could try to use the ```std::move``` , or you could modify unique_ptr with shared_ptr

Comment: Herb Sutter would recommend `void Reception::handleKitchenRet(k_ctrl_t const& kitch)`, or `void Reception::handleKitchenRet(k_ctrl_t& kitch)` or `void Reception::handleKitchenRet(k_ctrl_t const* kitch)` or `void Reception::handleKitchenRet(k_ctrl_t* kitch)`.  Only have a `unique_ptr` as a parameter if you are passing ownership.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Reception::handleKitchenRet(std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t> kitch)
```

is taking a `unique_ptr` by *value*.

To take it by *reference*, change the signature to

```
void Reception::handleKitchenRet(std::unique_ptr<k_ctrl_t>& kitch)
```